# Play audio from ajax call using audio.srcObject and a MediaStream

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio, mediastream, createobjecturl

I've implemented an HTTPS endpoint in php that returns mp3 data. Then, after an ajax call in javascript, I play it via the following:

```
let blob = new Blob([response.value], { type: 'audio/mp3' });

 cleanup = () => {
   // Not 100% sure this is needed:
   audio.src = '';
   // But this is:
   URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
 };

 let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
 let audio = new Audio();

 audio.addEventListener('ended', cleanup);

 audio.src = url;

 audio.play();
```

This seems to be working somewhat, but I'm hitting some browser issues in Fx playback bugs and some Chrome devtools crashes. I assume that maybe these issues are based on my use of `URL.createObject()`. It sounds like in the future the way to do this will be to set `audio.srcObject` instead, but [it's not ready in Chrome yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject), at least not for `Blob`s. `MediaStream`s are supported, but I can't find a way to create a `MediaStream` from the response body of my request.

So, my question: is there a way to play my mp3 using `audio.srcObject = someMediaStream`? Or do I need to stick with `URL.createObjectURL` until `audio.srcObject = new Blob()` is supported? This will only be running in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a MediaStream from an AudioElement playing the media from  the blob:// URI using the [MediaElement.`captureStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream) method, but that would defeat the purpose since you would still have to play that media on the source <audio> element.

You could also read your Blob as an ArrayBuffer, then decode this media's audio data using an AudioContext and its [`decodeAudioData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) method, then passing the resulting AudioBuffer to an AudioBufferSourceNode and finally connecting this latter to a [MediaStreamSourceNode.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource)

But... the bugs you describe are most probably not caused by your use of the blob:// URI, **which is currently indeed the best way to play an audio media**.

Hopefully someday browsers will implement the specs entirely and we will be able to pass other objects as `srcObject`, *and maybe even see it spread to other elements*, but I stopped holding my breath a few years ago...

**So yes, continue to use the blob:// URI**, and [file reports](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) to chromium's team about their bugs.

---

---

Ps: if you can, setting the `src` directly to the URL you do fetch using AJAX is actually the best option.

Comment: Thanks. I began with setting src directly, but my endpoint receives a json body,--and is a POST--so I ended up with the above.